# What regular expression to use in preg_match() for this?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, html-parsing, preg-match

I'm not really familiar with regular expressions, and I would really need your help with this.

I'm parsing a source code of a site, and the information I'm interested (lets call it XXXX) is surrounded by the following code:

```
                Number of people
        </p>
        <p style="font-size: 150%;">
            <b>XXXX</b>
```

Note: I have copied this directly from the source code, so you can see the indents and everything (if that's important).

I've tried this, but the preg_match() returns 0:

```
$regex = '~Number of people</p><p style="font-size: 150%;"><b>(.+?)</b>~';
```

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 3):

you have forgotten all the white characters (space, tab, newline) in your pattern:

```
~Number of people\s*</p>\s*<p style="font-size: 150%;">\s*<b>(.+?)</b>~
```

or better

```
~Number of people\s*</p>\s*<p style="font-size: 150%;">\s*<b>\K[^<]+~
```

But keep in mind that the good way to parse HTML is to use the DOM. (You don't give enough source code for an example)

Comment: Thanks Casimir, but I get this error when I use any of those two regular expressions:

"PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE"